# Remove the "Custom" argument from PayPal transaction details

Tags: woocommerce, paypal

I'm using Woocommerce with the PayPal standard payment features. In my orders transaction details there is a "Custom" string like the following:

> {"order_id":26143,"order_key":"wc_order_sHM1ITT24fTC9"}

I really don't like my customers to see this field in the transaction details.

I was wondering what is the "custom" argument for? Is this argument essential for the plugin to work or can it be removed?

Here is the filter I would like to use to unset the "Custom" argument. Does it make sense?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_paypal_args', 'custom_paypal_args', 10, 2 );
function custom_paypal_args($args, $order) {
    unset($args["custom"]);  //Remove the custom argument 
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customers don't see that value in their transaction details. Only the receiver of the transaction sees it.

WooCommerce uses that JSON data to reconcile notifications about the payment status (usually received via IPN), with orders in its database

---

There are many plugins available for PayPal payments via WooCommerce, and it does not necessarily ship with the best one. I would recommend trying this one if you haven't already: https://woocommerce.com/woocommerce-and-paypal/